# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: oracle, jsp

Here is my query,

```
select count(*) from "+table1+" where 
  latitude = '"+selectedlat+"' and       
  longitude = '"+selectedlong+"' and 
  observation_date between  TO_DATE('"+selectedobstime+"','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND 
  TO_DATE('"+selectedobstime+"','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

When i am running this query on jsp page its showing non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

Comment: What is the actual value for `selectedobstime`?  Whatever it is doesn't seem to be in the format you've specified. And why are you searching between two copies of the same value?

Comment: what are your values for the variables?

Comment: And what is the datatype of latitude and logitute

Comment: latitude and longitude  datatypes are number

Comment: datatype of latitude and logitute are number

Comment: select count(*) from t_xbt_meta_unique where latitude = 13 and longitude = 80.67 and observation_date between TO_DATE(03/22/2013 AM 9:02:00,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE(03/19/2016 AM 6:15:00,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: `03/22/2013 AM 9:02:00` is not in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss`.

Comment: in the database its stored as 03/22/2013 AM 9:02:00 but in the programin jsp we written query as  mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss

Comment: If it is a date column then it is not stored with a format. It has an internal representation; you just see it formatted by your client when you query it. What is the actual string value of `selectedobstime ` when it is embedded in your query?

Answer (score 0):

If your actual value for `selectedobstime` is, as you seem to suggest in a comment, `'2001-08-20 AM 11:43:00'` then that is not in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss`.

You would need to use a format model like:

```
TO_DATE('"+selectedobstime+"','yyyy-mm-dd AM hh:mi:ss')
```

The AM/PM indicator is needed, and you need the 12-hour `HH` rather than the 24-hour `HH24` for the hour portion. [Read more about date/time format elements](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA).

Comment: @Sony - I can't help you if you don't tell us what your actual value coming from JSP is. Is someone typing in the value? If so what exactly are they entering?

Comment: @Sony - that's not how this site works. The question needs the relevant information. The vital thing you haven't shown is *what the actual string value is*.

Comment: We need the **actual value** of the `selectedobstime` string. You are trying to convert that to a date, to match the table column. That's fine. But the format mask you are using in `to_date()` has to match the actual string value you're trying to convert.

Comment: 2001-08-20 AM 11:43:00